# Formatting text and bullet points

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, formatting

I am trying to add some short lines of bullet point text in an html5 css3 responsive web page so that when the automatic line breaks occur it only happens in front of a bullet point e.g.

So this:

---

#### Performer

★1 Hour Show  ★Golden Oldies  ★Sing a long  ★Aussie Flavour

---

Becomes this:

---

#### Performer

★1 Hour Show  ★Golden Oldies 
 ★Sing a long  ★Aussie Flavour

---

not this:

---

#### Performer

★1 Hour Show  ★Golden Oldies  ★Sing 
 along  ★Aussie Flavour

---

what I have is:

```
<h3>Performer</h3>
<p> &#x2605;1 Hour Show  &#x2605;Golden Oldies  &#x2605;Sing along  &#x2605;Aussie Flavour </p>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the bullets in `<span>` elements and give property `white-space: nowrap` to them. See code below:

```css
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h3>Performer</h3>
<p> <span>&#x2605;1 Hour Show</span> <span>&#x2605;Golden Oldies</span> <span>&#x2605;Sing along</span> <span>&#x2605;Aussie Flavour</span> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different method. Please check the below codes:

**Method 1**

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Performer</h3>
<p> <span>&#x2605;1 Hour Show</span> <span>&#x2605;Golden Oldies</span> <span>&#x2605;Sing along</span> <span>&#x2605;Aussie Flavour</span> </p>
```

**Method 2**

```css
span{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<h3>Performer</h3>
<p> <span>&#x2605;1 Hour Show</span> <span>&#x2605;Golden Oldies</span> <span>&#x2605;Sing along</span> <span>&#x2605;Aussie Flavour</span> </p>
```

**Method 3**

```css
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h3>Performer</h3>
<p> <span>&#x2605;1 Hour Show</span> <span>&#x2605;Golden Oldies</span> <span>&#x2605;Sing along</span> <span>&#x2605;Aussie Flavour</span> </p>
```

Comment: Thank you both for you help I will attempt to implement.

Comment: After trying out all suggestions I found < display:inline-block;> worked to solve the problem, Thanks again for the help folks :)

Comment: Welcome, if you don't mind please vote/accept the best answer :)